# How to I tell my imagePickerController delegate that my custom UIButton is handling the taking of the picture

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, delegates, uiimagepickercontroller

How can I get instruct the imagepickercontroller delegate to allow my custom UIButton to take a picture and then store it in an imageView file in the didFinishPickingImage delegate method?? Help would be much appreciated.

```
 @IBAction func takePicture(sender: AnyObject) {   
    imagePicker.takePicture()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    overlayView.opaque = true
    overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.showsCameraControls = false
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = overlayView

    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement [didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:) delegate. When you take the picture using your custom capture button, this delegate method will be called.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
      didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
{
    let image: UIImage  = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage;
    yourImageView.image = image;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and then how do I access it from there?

Comment: @JamieBaker: You can get the image from the `info` dictionary. Added more information

Answer (score 0):

Not possible through the imagepickercontroller's delegate. You have to use it as is. In case you want your custom button to do something - you have to write your own imagepickercontroller, unfortunately.

Comment: Is there no way to respond to my IBAction that instructs my picker to take a picture??

Comment: No. You have to 'build' your own camera picker view.